# UINavigationBar + largeTitleDisplayMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have next code

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
}
```

I have UIScrollView with textFields. When keyboard appear and I scrolling to bottom, navigationBar become small and it's correct. But when keyboard disappear navigationBar still small. I want that navigation bar to be a large when keyboard disappear.

[Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnktctws61oabwu/Untitled.mov?dl=0)

[image: Normal state]

[image: When keyboard dismiss]

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to scroll up a bit after hiding keyboard so it will trigger the `UINavigationBar` mode to switch to large.

**UPD:**
After trying your settings I found out that `UINavigationBar` becomes large only at the top of `UIScrollView`. So if you want it to be large again you should programmatically scroll.